# Sitecore 6.5 Accessing Analytics Database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I was wondering if the Sitecore Analytics database can be accessed via the API.

I have looked at the engagement analytics api reference, but that seems to be orientated towards tracking individual users and their sessions, i.e. I haven't been able to pull out records directly from the database.

I am writing an agent which will do stuff with the records in the pages table, but first I must get all the records out. I could access it via plain old SQL but surely the sitecore API must have a way to get this data out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own calls to SQL to pull out the data I needed.